# Place array of images one above the other partially in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to stack an array of images one above the other as shown in the attachment below. With the below code, I am able to stack them one beside the other, however could not overlap them. Appreciate any help.

```
{array1.edges.map((u, i) => {
  if (i > 5) return null;
  return (
    <Image
      source={{ uri: u.node.profilePhoto.url }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      key={i}
      style={{ height: 20, width: 20, borderRadius: 10 }}
    />
    );
}
)}
```

[image: overlapImages]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a negative marginLeft to around -10 to get that effect.
`marginLeft: -10`

Also followed this example rnplay.org/apps/LvdXgg to get it working.

Comment: Take a look at this example. https://rnplay.org/apps/LvdXgg


I don't know the exact value that would give you the look that you want. but I believe a negative margin should work. Can you share a picture of what you currently have?

Comment: @ Yo Wakita, thanks for your response. I followed your example and wrapped a container around the Image and set marginLeft: -10 and it worked... Thanks a lot, Appreciate it..